# Deleting large snapshot with limited datastore space

Tags: vmware-esxi

I've read best practices for using snapshots in ESXi, unfortunately I inherited system with VM's running on snapshots for longer than they should be.  In one instance that's concerning me, the delta VMDK has grown larger than the original VMDK off of which it was running.  These VMDK's are about 57 and 43 GB, respectively.  In addition to this, I only have about 22 GB left on my datastore.  Are either of these going to cause issues or is it fairly safe to delete this snapshot?  I'm using ESXi 4.1.

Comment: `I'm using ESXi 4.1` - Time to upgrade. - http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1023657

Answer (score 1):

Try and see.

What else can you do?

You can't let the snapshot run forever. And you're going to have to consolidate the disk files at some point.